# Cannot restrict JQuery UI tooltip on form input field to be displayed on click/focus event only

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, tooltip, onfocus

Basically I am trying to display JQuery UI tooltip on focus event only (on a form input field). It works fine the first time around... it opens the tooltip and on blur closes it. But the second click in the input field does nothing! Please help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name='fname']").tooltip({ 
            position: { my: "left top", at: "left-30 bottom+10" },
        hide: { effect: "fold", duration: 400 },
        disabled: true
          });

 $("input[name='fname']").tooltip({ content: "Please enter your first name."});
 $("input[name='fname']").focus(function (){
            $("input[name='fname']").tooltip("enable");      
            $("input[name='fname']").tooltip("open");return false; 
 });

 $("input[name='fname']").blur(function(){
           $("input[name='fname']").tooltip("close");
           $("input[name='fname']").tooltip("disable");return false;
 }); 

});

</script>
```

The form is much longer but I thought just one field should suffice to focus on the problem. There is not much discussion on the topic and the suggestions offered do not work.

Comment: I struggled with it... then I just thought of trying something. I put some dummy text in the title attribute and Voila! it works. But now my question is why? I saw the items and contents options are related and they speak about the title attribute for event delegation. Can someone tie all this together? I think it will help others too. It is a very common need to have tooltips only onfocus for form fields. Thanks

Comment: Ideally, when using tooltips, you should provide the title text in html and not in Javascript. This way you do not need to use: { content: "Please enter your first name."} I suspect the reason why your code wasn't working was because you first set the tool-tip content for all inputs with name=fname, then after you click away you disable ALL the input tooltips, that is why I mentioned you should reassign 'content' after you disable your tooltips. Otherwise once you disable tooltips they will never re-appear.

Comment: @RealityDysfunction: Thanks. I now understand the logic behind your suggestion.  ...after disabling it, it relies upon the Title content and cannot enable it back because the Title content is NULL. Let me play with it now that I understand the why behind the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems I suspect:

1) in such lines as: `$("input[name='fname']").tooltip("enable");` `$("input[name='fname']").tooltip("open");return false;` Change the `input[name='fname']` to `(this)`

2) Try moving this line: `$("input[name='fname']").tooltip({ content: "Please enter your first name."});` immediately after this line:

```
$("input[name='fname']").tooltip("disable");return false;
```

Comment: I had tried the first suggestion. Let me try the second one and see.

Comment: By move, I meant copy that line there as well.

Comment: I tried copy too. Either way, open, close, enable, disable do not destroy the tooltip or reset its properties. Therefore, the need to reset content again would have been a bug in the tooltip widget anyway. Or so I think. It took me some time to figure this out. I am surprised that other threads on this "tooltip on click only" try other approaches which simply do not work.

Comment: Just thought of putting some closing thoughts after realizing that I had left it open. In using tooltips on focus only,  simply set disabled: true when creating it. Then onfocus event, enable it and then open it as in: $(".tool_tip1").focus(function (){$(this).tooltip("enable"); $(this).tooltip("open");return false; }); and onblur event, just disable and close it. Also, set all title text in HTML or at least set title to an empty string in the HTML if you are going to use the "content" property. The comments above helped put this together.